# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I am getting the following `Exception` from the `View`.

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type
>   'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Profile_Id'.

**From View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Profile_Id", String.Empty)
```

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult Index( string name, string Profile_Id, int? page)
{

    ...
    ViewBag.Profile_Id = new SelectList(db.PROFILE.Where(y => y.ID== myId ), "Profile_Id", "Name");

    return View(prof.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are not getting this error the first time this view is rendered from the GET /Index action but rather when you submit the corresponding form to your POST action which renders the same view.

To fix this error make sure that **inside your POST action** you also populate the `Profile_Id` property like you did in the GET action if you intend to render the same view because it depends on it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ... process the data

    // populate the Profile_Id property because we are
    // redisplaying the same view which depends on it in order
    // to show the corresponding dropdown
    ViewBag.Profile_Id = new SelectList(db.PROFILE.Where(y => y.ID== myId ), "Profile_Id", "Name");

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Let me try this out. Anyways, you have an amazing profile.